# Cannot add item to observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This should be a pretty trivial question, but it's getting me crazy!
I't like step 1 of the tutorial, but I can't it to work.... so this is my code:

```
/* Model definition */
    var PrivateSalesMenuModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.privateSales = ko.observableArray();
    this.addPrivateSale = function (privateSale) {
        var newPs = new PrivateSaleMenuItem(privateSale);
        self.privateSales.push(newPs);
    };
};

var PrivateSaleMenuItem = function (ps) {
    this.title = ps.Description;
    this.hasActual = ps.HasActual;
    this.hasSale = ps.HasSale;
    this.listaId = ps.ListaId;
    this.isSelected = false;
};
/* end model definition*/

var privateSalesMenuModel = new PrivateSalesMenuModel();

ko.applyBindings(privateSalesMenuModel);
```

Pretty simple... I have an object that represent my model, that is a collection of others objects, called `PrivateSaleMenuItem`.
Problem is that `addPrivateSale` didn't work as expected. Somewhere in the code I do

```
privateSalesMenuModel.addPrivateSale(ps);
```

where ps is an object created by other JavaScript functions... anyway is exactaly the object I need in the constructor of PrivateSaleMenuItem, so it's consistency is not the problem.
The problem seems o be that `self.privateSales.push(newPs);` doesn't work... after that inocation, the number of `privateSalesMenuModel.privateSales` is still 0.
Why is that?

**Edited**

I put toghether an example in jsFiddle with this same exact code, and it works fine, so I suspect something in my page make the push method of observableArray stop working... how can I find out what it is?

ops... the link of jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YBHf5/

Comment: do you get any console errors?

Comment: `ko.observableArray()` is defined?... the function return a correct array? the method is accessible?

Comment: @Tanner: nope, everything's clean.

Comment: @Frogmouth: I thought that it shuold throw some exceptions if the function wouldn't be accessible or stuff like that? Am I wrong? How can I answer to your question properly? I saw that debugging, I get into the knockuotjs code that implement the push... so I think the method call is valid...

Comment: check the object that you get from that other function and pass to the constructor. There might be some error like typo in property name when you are assigning the values.

Comment: @Matus: I even added to my code a plain add, like the one you find on the jsfiddle provided: `privateSalesMenuModel.addPrivateSale({ Description: "pluto", HasActual: false, HasSale: true, ListaId: "pluto" });` even this doesn't work

Comment: Actually I copied all the code from the fiddle in my page, stripping out every other usage of the model, and still... it doesn't work. there's something avoiding knockout to work properly I think, but a don't know how to find out what it is... the real page is very complex and I'd like to avoid cutting out small pieces of code, without here and there to see if it sart working...

Comment: `ko` ... ko object is a framework (knockout)... I don't know this framework i'm so sorry... the only one thing that I say is the returned data from `ko.observableArray()` isn't an array but is a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.... it was a trivial problem indeeed, with a trivial solution: I just needed to push the external script declaration at the end of the page.
I had the script (in which the code provided on the question is present) at the top of the page, inside the body, but above anything else.
Just putting the script reference at the end of the body and everything works as expected again.
Sorry for wasting your time... but this little issue is very hard to find out, 'cause the reason is not clear at all while debugging

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are mixing this and self in your code here:

```
    var PrivateSalesMenuModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.privateSales = ko.observableArray();
    this.addPrivateSale = function (privateSale) {
        var newPs = new PrivateSaleMenuItem(privateSale);
        self.privateSales.push(newPs);
    };
};
```

Changing them to all use self fixes it like this:

```
var PrivateSalesMenuModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.privateSales = ko.observableArray();
    self.addPrivateSale = function (privateSale) {
        var newPs = new PrivateSaleMenuItem(privateSale);
        self.privateSales.push(newPs);
    };
};
```

Please see working fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YBHf5/1/

Comment: Long shot but do you have an external link I can view it on?